# Из xib по кнопке в storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

По кнопке из сториборда (с навигационным контроллером) в хиб перехожу запросто а обратно не могу! прочитал кучу форумов, пишут:

```
 UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController* detailViewController= [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

У меня не работает, у кого нибудь работает?

Comment: ты лучше напиши как ты из сториборда (с навигационным контроллером) в ксиб переходишь, тогда, возможно, будет понятно как тебе помочь.

Comment: - (IBAction)xibButton:(id)sender

{
    LandscapeViewController *landscapeViewController = [[LandscapeViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:landscapeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: @SergeyXcode, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @SergeyXcode, вы запутываете окончательно))) 

Если вы пушите, тогда чтобы закрыть вызываете popViewControllerAnimated, если презентуете, тогда вызываете для закрытия dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion:. Ничего ведь сложного)

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; с работало вот так, а я вместо селфа всякие контролеры вставлял, всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self presentViewController:toController animated:YES completion:^{}]; // переход к другому контроллеру
[toController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}]; // обратно
```

Comment: спасибо думаю вы правы у меня так и не получилась наверно потому что на тот view  из storyboard подходит 10 segal  и я хочу вернуться на него с кнопки в alert менюшки ( которая стоит в didloady  авзапуском в xibe)!

Answer (score 2):

А так??))

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```